# CSS Font-Size Reset

Tags: css, font-size

I'm just wondering if there is any kind of CSS font-size Reset Code,
since I am doing a grid without float and had to set the font-size to 0

As a Result of that none of my Text inside that Div is showing up.

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:**

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NoahWetjen/ZgcJw/2/)**

Some way to do the Grid without setting the font-size to 0 would also be great.

This is the simplified Markup and CSS I'm using:

***HTML***

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="inner">

        <section id="left-area"> [...] </section>

        <section id="right-area"> [...] </section>

    </div>

</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1020px;
}

.container .inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    font-size: 0;
}

.container .inner section#left-area, .container .inner section#right-area {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: You really never should have to "set the font-size to 0", so in all likelihood there's a better way to do what you need to do. Give some more details of what you are trying to do and we can help out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) CSS Reset.

Here is the code:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

There are many resets, but like you said you need something specific for fonts, but this reset, when used in totality, has helped me for a lot of my projects including font-size and when used as full, shall fulfill your font-size requirement too. Hope this Helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i've already tried this, this messes up everything and the Text still isn't showing.

I'm looking for something that just resets the font-sizes to what they are in standard HTML

Comment: If you reduct the width of `.container .inner section#left-area, .container .inner section#right-area` from 150px to 148px and comment `font-size:0;` it works. -@NoahWetjen

Comment: True but fist this produces a gap between the two sections and also I'm using a Grid inside of this, so I can't just adjust the Width.

Comment: Here is the solution. http://jsfiddle.net/ZgcJw/8/ . Hope this solves your purpose. I have commented the `font-size:0` and the `display:inline-block` in the `.container .inner section#left-area, .container .inner section#right-area` and added a new css for `section` with `display:table-cell;`. I hope it works as what you want. - @NoahWetjen