# How do I find the width of a character in a textarea in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, special-characters

I need to find the width of a character in an HTML textarea element, in CSS `px`.

The best solution would use a JavaScript function that takes a character and returns its width, and must work with special characters like control characters (`\u0001`, `\u0096`, `\uFFFD` etc.) It would be even better if it also worked with Tabs given the index of the character in the textarea.

I already have [a function that does this (link here; my project is open-source and on GitHub)](https://github.com/WebCoder49/code-input/blob/display-special-chars/plugins/special-chars.js#LL151C9-L151C9) using an HTML5 textarea and works on Chromium, but it breaks in Firefox, especially since Firefox renders control characters differently in textareas ("hex boxes") to other elements.

```
getCharacterWidth(char) {
        // Force zero-width characters
        if(new RegExp("\u00AD|\u02de|[\u0300-\u036F]|[\u0483-\u0489]|\u200b").test(char) ) { return 0 }
        // Non-renderable ASCII characters should all be rendered at same size
        if(char != "\u0096" && new RegExp("[\u{0000}-\u{001F}]|[\u{007F}-\u{009F}]", "g").test(char)) {
            let fallbackWidth = this.getCharacterWidth("\u0096");
            return fallbackWidth;
        }
        // Lazy-load - TODO: Get a cleaner way of doing this
        if(char in this.cachedWidths) {
            return this.cachedWidths[char];
        }

        // Try to get width
        let width = this.canvasContext.measureText(char).width;
        this.canvasContext.fillText(char, 100, 100);
        if(width > 20) {
            width /= 2; // Fix double-width-in-canvas Firefox bug
        } else if(width == 0 && char != "\u0096") {
            let fallbackWidth = this.getCharacterWidth("\u0096");
            return fallbackWidth; // In Firefox some control chars don't render, but all control chars are the same width
        }

        this.cachedWidths[char] = width;
        return width;
    }
```

I would very much appreciate suggestions here, or a [PR in the project on GitHub forked from the `display-special-chars` branch](https://github.com/WebCoder49/code-input). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Reset the font to a particular font, then your canvas code is good -- to reset font you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771379/css-font-size-reset

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code.

```
// create a new canvas element
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// set the font size and type
ctx.font = '16px Arial';

// get the width of the character 'A'
const charWidth = ctx.measureText('A').width;
console.log(`The width of the character 'A' is ${charWidth}px`);
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: _How_ is it useful? What does it do to solve the OP's problem? You should add notes to your answer to add detail to your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I think this was the approach I was already trying. Please let me know if there is anything I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

> In JavaScript, you can find the width of a character in a textarea by creating a temporary element, setting its font to match the font of the textarea, and then measuring the width of the character in the temporary element using the offsetWidth property. Here's an example function that takes a character and a textarea element, and returns the width of the character in pixels

```
function getCharacterWidth(char, textarea) {
// Create a temporary element to measure the width of the character
const temp = document.createElement('span');
temp.textContent = char;

// Copy the textarea's font to the temporary element
temp.style.font = getComputedStyle(textarea).font;

// Add the temporary element to the document so we can measure its width
document.body.appendChild(temp);

// Get the width of the character in pixels
const width = temp.offsetWidth;

// Remove the temporary element from the document
document.body.removeChild(temp);

return width;
}
```

---

You can call this function with a character and a textarea element to get the width of the character in pixels:

```
const charWidth = getCharacterWidth('a', 
document.querySelector('textarea'));
console.log(`The width of the character 'a' in the textarea is 
${charWidth}px`);
```

- Note that this function only works for monospaced fonts. If the textarea uses a proportional font, the width of each character will vary depending on the specific character and the surrounding text.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion - it works with many characters. However, in **Firefox** with **special characters** it does not seem to work, and the width of the characters is returned as `0`. If anybody knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCharWidthInTextarea(char, textarea) {
    // Create a temporary span element with the same font properties as the textarea
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(textarea).fontSize;
    span.style.fontFamily = window.getComputedStyle(textarea).fontFamily;
    span.style.fontWeight = window.getComputedStyle(textarea).fontWeight;
    span.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    span.style.position = 'absolute';
    span.textContent = char;

    // Append the span element to the document body
    document.body.appendChild(span);

    // Get the width of the character using the offsetWidth property of the span 
    var width = span.offsetWidth;

    // Remove the span element from the document body
    document.body.removeChild(span);

    // Return the width of the character
    return width;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this extension of the previous answer. However, it still does not fix the Firefox Special Character bug, and they still return a width of `0`. Please let me know if you have any more suggestions.